# Having multiple suffix for same directive (angularjs)

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

Let say we have the following directive:

```
app.directive('testList', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            //do stuff
        }
    }
});
```

I would like to call this directive from multiple element in html

```
<button test-list-add></button>
 <table test-list="listObject">
    <tr ng-repeat="list in testList">
       <td test-list-click>list.item</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

is it possible to get into the `link` function for each attribute starting with `test-list` (`test-list-add`, `test-list`, `test-list-click`)?

Thank you

Comment: You can try searching by attributes, but what are you trying to do exactly ? the kind of usage you're trying to do make me thinks that you should take a look at transcluding. Or you should specify a template in your directive so you can put all your attributes in one dom element and generate the template that you need

Comment: Thanks, for your comment, I also think I should look at transcluding, but since I'm new in angular I want to do it progressively.As I understand transcluding helps me to reformat the html, but if I have events in there I should also use the $compile, shouldn't I?

Comment: There is two of using transcluding, either put ng-transclude in your template, or call it in your link function like this : angular.element([ttransclude element of your template]).appendChild(transclude(scope.$parent)); Note that to have scope.$parent working you must use scope:true and not isolated scope. For the event part, angular wrap almost all native events, with ng-click, ng-focus, ng-blur,.... but you can just inject $compile in your directive and use it in the link function and after add the transcluded element to the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to pass attributes to your directive and doing some action, depending on the attribute:

```
app.directive('testList', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
           'add': '@', // Text
           'click': '&' // function
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            // scope.add - your Text you passed
            // scope.click(); - calls your function you passed
        }
    }
});

<button test-list add="test"></button>
 <table test-list="listObject">
    <tr ng-repeat="list in testList">
       <td test-list click="myFunc()">list.item</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

You can't repeat a directive (what you obvis trying to do).

If you want to make multiple suffix for a directive, you have to declare them one by one:

```
app.directive('testListAdd', function () {...});
app.directive('testListclick', function () {...});

<test-list-add></test-list-add>
<test-listclick></test-listclick>
```